# Accessing a value in a subclass as a property vs. by index for List<>

Tags: c#, parse-platform, subclass

I've created a subclass of ParseObject. I have a property of type List. When I attempt to get the value using the property, I get a null; if I access the value using the property name as an index, I get the expected value, a list of strings.

I would expect these techniques to be equivalent, and accessing by property even preferable, given that it doesn't expose you to spelling errors. Can anyone help me understand (a) why they are not equivalent, and (b) how I can successfully access the value via the property?

Example:

```
[ParseClassName( "MyThing" )]
public class MyThing : ParseObject
{
    [ParseFieldName( "Name" )]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return GetProperty< string >( "Name" ); }
        set { SetProperty< string >( value, "Name" ); }
    }

    [ParseFieldName( "Notes" )]
    public List< string > Notes
    {
        get { return GetProperty< List< string > >( "Notes" ); }
        set { SetProperty< List< string > >( value, "Notes" ); }
    }
}

elsewhere...

    var name    = aThing.Name;      // I get the expected name
    var asProp  = aThing.Notes;     // I get *null*
    var asIndex = aThing["Notes"];  // I get an array of strings
```

Comment: What happens if you change it to `GetProperty<string[]>` instead?

Comment: I don't understand. Just changing the getter would then return a type incompatible with the property type. Do you mean change the whole thing to string[]?

Comment: Yes, essentially. As a kind of sanity-check. I haven't used the `parse` library but I think it's semi-likely that it's strict about its collections; while it thinks the property is an array, you've asked for a list. If the array *does* work, then either you'd put logic in the property to convert to/from array and list - or you just proceed with using the array instead of the list.

Comment: Well, I tried a variant on your proposed experiment, and changed the declaration from List<> to IList<> -- and it worked!  Looking in VS, it seems that the actual type returned by Parse is Parse.Internal.FlexibleListWrapper, so I guess that explains it. Thanks for helping me reflect on this. (No pun intended, but I'll take it. (: )

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that you have to declare the type as IList<>, not List<>. I misinterpreted the Parse documentation that says among supported data types:

```
objects that implement IList<T>
```

to mean that one can actually use an implementation of IList<>. Not so: the type Parse returns from its GetProperty<IList> is Parse.Internal.FlexibleListWrapper. A concrete value is compatible for the SetProperty<>, but not the GetProperty<>.

Moral of the story, I suppose, is that Parse will not concern itself with trying to convert to whatever concrete type you throw at it, which seems reasonable enough. If you want to keep the concrete type in your property declaration, you can always do a conversion in your getter.